# RPC get free address

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

Always when i need free address (not labled) i use:

```
getAccountAddress('')
```

And i want to know: Can it give me an already occupied address (by label)

I'm worried that I can get an already address in using (by label)

Comment: Why not just use `getnewaddress`?  The whole account / label system is deprecated and shouldn't be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide an empty string it will return the default account every time. Note `getaccountaddress` is deprecated, see https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.2/rpc/wallet/getaccountaddress/.

```
getaccountaddress "account"

DEPRECATED. Returns the current Bitcoin address for receiving payments to this account.

Arguments:
1. "account"       (string, required) The account name for the address. It can also 
be set to the empty string "" to represent the default account. The account does not
need to exist, it will be created and a new address created  if there is no account
by the given name.
```